# Reading Android attributes on my custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have created a custom layout class (extends RelativeLayout) and have a TextView as part of the layout.

I want to apply the properties declared in XML to my TextView, is there anyway I can read the android attributes (not my custom attributes, that part is already taken care of).

For example in my XML I'll have this:

```
<my.custom.MyLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="SomeText" />
```

I want to read the text attribute and apply it to my TextView (currently it is being applied to the RelativeLayout) instead of creating my own attribute and reading it.

My custom layout is something like this :

```
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView textView;
    public void MyLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        /**Read android attributes and apply it to TextView **/
        ??
    }
```

My current solution is creating custom attributes and reading them, but I feel that is not a good solution as I'll be duplicating every attribute declared to TextView.

More info about my current solution.

I have a custom attribute called myText which I use to apply the text declared in XML to my TextView.

In my layout XML :

```
myNameSpace:myText="SomeText"
```

And read it in my Java class :

```
String text= a.getString(R.styleable.MyStyleable_myText);
textView.setText(text);
```

I'm looking to get rid of my custom attributes and read "android:" attributes.

Comment: if `MyLayout` is your custom component then you can write getter to get any attribute or anything

Comment: I want to read the XML attribute, for example `android:text="SomeText"` as part of the attrs value which is passed to the constructor of every View. I can't use getters for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I am not sure if setting `android:text` will be possible for view extending `RelativeLayout`. If it is possible do it like in `TextView` implementation:

```
final Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
text = a.getText(attr);
```

So basically it's the same way you get your custom properties but with different styleable.

If it's not working I would consider another approach. I did it for one of my custom views. Since you have a `TextView` in your custom view you could create it in XML and then get a reference to that child inside your custom view.

```
<YourCustomView>
    <TextView android:text="someText"/>
<YourCustomView/>
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, that styleable is what I was looking for. And text was just for an example, I want to copy other properties like width and height.

Comment: What is `attr`?

Comment: @Eido95 It's an attribute index. I copied that from TextView source code so it's best if you have a look there. You can check it from IDE or here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#784